# I Want to convert lat and lat to get the name of place marker in website?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, google-maps

Iam Using this library  https://github.com/wimagguc/jquery-latitude-longitude-picker-gmaps 
to make map with marker 
and use in the backend laravel 
i want to get the name of place where the marker located on it 
how can i do it ?! 
in the database i am saved the lat and lng 
any way to get the name of place ??? 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBFsP.png)

Comment: Just checked the screenshot you have, please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score -1):

Reverse Geocoding in Geocoding API would be able to help you convert latlng coordinates into addresses. You may refer to this documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding

Here is a sample HTTP request: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=YOUR_API_KEY

However, kindly note that, and as mentioned in the doc, Reverse geocoding is an estimate. The geocoder will attempt to find the closest addressable location within a certain tolerance. If no match is found, the geocoder will return zero results.

I hope this helps!